# Create a SQL task and mapping parameters

Tags: sql, if-statement, ssis, sql-server-2012, parameter-passing

I have a file name  “Sales_20170331”.
Now I need to load a fact table from this file.
The table has columns Sale_quarter_date, SaleId 
The sale_quarter_date  column is loading from the @FileName variable that I created in ssis.
Now I need to create execute sql task in SSIS that will delete the rows in the fact table where sale_quarter_date  = @FileName. If quarter_date  != @FileName then load those records.
The query should look something like

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Facttable]') AND type in (N'U') 
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[FactTable]) >0)

DELETE FROM [dbo].[FactTable] 
WHERE sale_quarter_date = @FileName
```

But looks like there is some error here in the query.
Can you please help me fix the query and design the execute sql task?

Comment: And what is this "some error"? What error message do you get?

Comment: Not able to map to this particular @filename varaiable to the key column i'm trying to get this date from

Comment: I don't see any error in your query.  The problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current query that you have written for execution does not address the need 'if quarter_date != FileName'. Here is what you can do -

1. Create a variable sSaleQuarterDate_Existing
2. Use 'Execute SQL Task' and write a query with which you obtain the existing Sale Quarter Date such as the one below. Set 'ResultSet' as 'Single Row' and in the 'ResultSet' add assign the result set-

   select max(SaleQuarterDate) as 'SaleQuarterDate' from dbo.Facttable
3. Now create the 'Data Flow Task' that is used for loading. Connect the above task to this task. Double-Click on the connection and set the Evaluation Expression as - Expression and Constraint. In the Expression give the condition - @[User::FileName] != sSaleQuarterDate_Existing.
4. Create another 'Execute SQL Task'. This is the one that needs to be used to delete the existing records from the table when condition matches. Connect the task from 'Step 2' to this task. Again do the same steps as in 'Step 3' but this time change the condition to --@[User::FileName] == sSaleQuarterDate_Existing. In this taks have the same query that you have written.

The error that most probably you are facing is, you giving the parameter name itself. Try modifying the query as below -

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Facttable]') AND type in (N'U') 
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[FactTable]) >0)

DELETE FROM [dbo].[FactTable] 
WHERE sale_quarter_date = ?
```

In the 'Parameter Mapping' window, assign the 'FileName' user variable.

Comment: Thank you so much Karthik. This helped. I think the problem was that i was giving the parameter name directly in the query.And now instead of having 2 separate tasks i just gave the delete statement and the insert statement for the required condition in the same task and it works fine now.

Comment: Yw. Could you just mark it as answered? This will help narrow down the unanswered questions.